# Executing a Insert Stored Procedure in a For Loop in MS Access

Tags: arrays, sql-server, ms-access, stored-procedures, bulkinsert

I am building a application in Microsoft Access that uses SQL Server as the backend. I have code that pulls in some customer information from a different source and stores it in an Array. The array is dynamic, and the number of elements will always be different.

In this case, The array has 59 elements. Right now, I execute the stored procedure to insert this customer data in a For Loop which executes the stored procedure 59 times.

I have been researching on how to pass an array as a parameter, but I haven't had any luck. My code works fine, But I am just wondering if there is a better, more efficient way to do this instead of executing the stored procedure n amount of times.

```
For i = 0 To C.lngArraySize - 1
      Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim Prm As ADODB.Parameter
  With cmd

    .CommandText = "spAddAccountArray_INS"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection

    Set Prm = .CreateParameter("@pID", adInteger, , , C.ReturnCustomerID)
    .Parameters.Append Prm

    Set Prm = .CreateParameter("@pName", adVarChar, , 50, C.aeName(i))
    .Parameters.Append Prm

    Set Prm = .CreateParameter("@pType", adVarChar, , 30, "Authorized Employee")
    .Parameters.Append Prm

    Set Prm = .CreateParameter("@pacct", adVarChar, , 16, C.aeAccount(i))
    .Parameters.Append Prm

    .Execute
    End With
    Set cmd = Nothing
Next i
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best performance will be to package up the data into xml, and ship it down to Sql Server (through a stored procedure) and shred it there, and then do the insert.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa905917(v=sql.80).aspx

Do NOT create xml they way the article explains.

```
  sXMLDoc = "<ROOT>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "<Customers CustomerID='VINET' ContactName='Paul Henriot'>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "<Orders CustomerID='VINET' EmployeeID='5' OrderDate='1996-07-04T00:00:00'>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "<Order_0020_Details OrderID='10248' ProductID='11' Quantity='12'/>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "<Order_0020_Details OrderID='10248' ProductID='42' Quantity='10'/>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "</Orders>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "</Customers>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "<Customers CustomerID='LILAS' ContactName='Carlos Gonzlez'>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "<Orders CustomerID='LILAS' EmployeeID='3' OrderDate='1996-08-16T00:00:00'>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "<Order_0020_Details OrderID='10283' ProductID='72' Quantity='3'/>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "</Orders>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "</Customers>"
   sXMLDoc = sXMLDoc & "</ROOT>"
```

That is embarrassing that it even exists on the msdn site.  use the msxml2.domdocument object to create xml.  do NOT use string concatenation to cretae xml.

A couple of notes

1. Why (in 2016) are you creating an Access front end?  Its horrible for maintenance.  Try a DotNet winforms object (at the least) with proper Business Logic and Data Access Logic layers.
2. OPENXML has been updated since Sql Server 2000.  See:

http://pratchev.blogspot.com/2007/06/shredding-xml-in-sql-server-2005.html

Comment: I will take a look at the XML method. I am using Access because it's an application that needs to be developed quickly and it is what I have experience with. I am new to SQL Server and don't have the capacity to learn how to build a dotnet winforms application right now. Once the application is built in Access, my next step is to move it to a web application.

Comment: "Developed Quickly".  The time you spend maintaining a proof-of-concept application will trump the little bit of time needed to come up to speed on the basic 3 layer application.  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/dacca2/understand-3-tier-architecture-in-C-Sharp-net/